# How to create universal list of items on Angular 2?

Tags: angular

There are many modules in my application, and in each module I need to have a list of all the elements. The list looks lonely and performs the same functions, I want to render it in a separate component, but I ran into a problem, the elements in each module have different fields. For example

```
class Person {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   ...
}
class Address {
   id: number;
   street: string
   ...
}
```

For person I want that list-component show list of names. For addresses I want that list-component show list of addresses
What best way to create universal list?

Example

navigation-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-list',
    templateUrl: './navigation-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation-list.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationListComponent {
    public searchString: string;

    @Input() navigationListItems: Array<NavigationListItem>;

    @Output() deletedElementId = new EventEmitter();

    public onDelete(id: number) {
        this.deletedElementId.emit(id);
    }

}
```

navigation-list.component.html

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchString">
</md-input-container>
<md-nav-list dense>
    <md-list-item>
        <button md-line md-raised-button routerLink="./">Create</button>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let listItem of ( navigationListItems | filterByName: searchString )">
        <a md-line routerLink={{listItem.id}}>{{ listItem.title }}</a>
        <button
                md-icon-button
                color="warn"
                (click)="onDelete(listItem.id)"
        >
            <i class="mkv-icon-navigation icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-nav-list>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more what you try to accomplish. What is "universal list" or "all the elements"? For example addd some concrete example data and the HTML you expect to be generated from that data. Usually in Angular you use `*ngFor` to generate lists. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context, https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: let list = any[]; ? Why not two lists? Why not if ('key' in list[i]) ?

Comment: If you're asking how to create several components sharing the same methods but displaying things in a different way, then you can just do that: have a parent class ListComponent<T>, containing an Array<T>, and common methods allowing to manipulate the array (add an item, etc.), and several subclasses like PersonListComponent extends ListComponent<Person>. Another way is to simply delegate the complex methods of the component to a shared class knowing how to handle the operations on the array.

Comment: @jb-nizet Can you give me a real example, please

Comment: No, I can't. You should start trying something on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single class and then convert the object as the universal class you created. Then use that object in your HTML.

```
class Person {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   ...
}
class Address {
   id: number;
   street: string
   ...
}
class UniversalClass {
    key: number,
    value: string
}

private CastObject(item: Address): UniversalClass {
    return new UniversalClass({
        key: item.id,
        value: item.street
    });
}
```